# NullPointerException whilst learning concurrency in Scala

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, nullpointerexception

I'm having a little problem at the moment. My latest assignment is to create a rock paper scissors program which will run concurrently and output various values. Sounds simple and trivial, I know, but a little fun and I have been allowed to use scala which I had no knowledge of so thought it would be interesting.

Now the error is confusing me. I am receiving a NullPointerException on Thread 10, and have spent an awful long time trying to find it to no success. I have 6 classes so it would be impractical of me to put all of the code in, but I will put a few snippets.

```
result = Shapes.Winner(player1.getChoice(), player2.getChoice())
```

This is the line giving the error. Player1 and Player2 are simply objects from a class I have made, and they have been dequeued in.

Now for the confusing part. If I add a simple line in another class:

```
println(wait.getChoice())
```

it all works. This line has no relation to the first line above, and was simply for testing. But now when I take it out, I get the error. I would just leave it, but as you can see, it prints a load of rubbish onto the terminal.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and would love some help.

Feel free to ask for more snippets of the code, and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What does the object/class look like that has the getChoice() method and what does the block of code that instantiates "wait" look like?

Comment: @kondrak 

`var choice: String = "Error 4: String not initliased correctly"
    var num: Int = 0
    var winornot: MVar[Int] = new MVar[Int]()
    
    def getChoice(): String = {
      return choice
    }`

That is a snippet from the class that contains getChoice()

`val wait: Playing = new Playing()
      wait.setChoice(choice: String)
      wait.setNum(i: Int)
      println(wait.getChoice())
      Referee.queue += wait`

Comment: You should probably edit your question to include the code, not paste it into a comment.  Hard to parse in comment format.

Comment: Please, create a https://gist.github.com/ and put it in the question, if code is too large. It is impossible to reason about a code you haven't seen

Comment: @Bubbafat
I've spend all morning fiddling with it now and still have no clue, so help would be great!

Comment: waitingtoref is synchronized, but the caller isn't - so when it returns you are not thread safe any more.  This means that two threads could see 2 items in the queue, both say "I'm good!" and then both attempt to dequeue at the same time - taking 4 ... giving nulls.  You can't do a synchronized test and trust the answer outside of the sync block.  What if the signature of your function was something like:  def waitingtoref(): (Player, Player)   ... think about how that would allow you to dequeue safely.

Comment: @Bubbafat If you are talking about referee threads pulling multiple items out of the queue, then that won't happen, because there is only ever one referee thread.

Comment: @Bubbafat The waitingtoref() method is essentially just a way of stopping the single referee jumping in to early which returns a "queue empty" error. All that method does is allows the referee to wait until he is notified that the queue has been added to and that there are more than 2 Players in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `synchronized` incorrectly. You should wrap all calls to `Referee.queue` into `Referee.synchronized {}` blocks in order to synchronization to work. Otherwise the calls are not synchronized, and it's possible for one thread to modify `Referee.queue` without other thread notice.

Otherwise you should use thread safe collection. For example when I substitute `scala.collection.mutable.Queue` with `scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedQueue` in the `Referee` class everything works ok, and you don't need to synchronize access to queue.
Even better use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead, because 
`SynchronizedQueue` is deprecated in scala_2.11

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I have added `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and it hasn't solved the problem? Do I still need to enclose the calls to the queue or make any changes to the program itself? Thanks again

Comment: Do you have same issue when you use scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedQueue ? If no, than you can simply wrap all instances where you access Referee.queue with Referee.synchronized { } and your code should work.

Comment: I have wrapped all instances in syncs and I am no longer getting the pointer exception, however I believe empty values are entering my queue (which is confusing as I initialise them all before they go in).

Comment: `Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error 1 (Shapes): error in winner switch
 at Shapes$.Winner(Shapes.scala:33)
 at Referee$.referee(Referee.scala:20)
 at RockPaperScissors$$anon$2.run(RockPaperScissors.scala:22)
` 
I am getting this error, which only happens when my switch reverts to default. @vitalii